# jQuery slide in sideways along with parent element

Tags: jquery, slide

I know similar questions have been asked before but what I want is for the parent to grow in size as the element slides in. I've tried many tricks including jQuery UI.

This is what I got so far: http://jsfiddle.net/U8z49/25/

**html**:

```html
<table class="t">
    <tr>
        <td class="l">
            <div>Click me.<br /><br />This div has fixed width of 100px and is taller than the right stuff.</div>
        </td>
        <td class="r">
            <div class="rdiv">I would like this cell or div to slide in from left to right and to cause the parent table and its background to grow along with it. Currently the table first snaps to 100% width, and then the content (the div) slides in.</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**css**:

```css
.t { background: #ddd; border-radius: 10px; width: auto; }
.l div { width: 120px; margin: 1em; text-align: right; }
.rdiv { padding: 1em; border-left: 1px solid #bbb; display: none; }
```

**js**:

```js
$('.l').click(function(){$('.rdiv').show("slide", {direction:"left"}, 500);});
```

As you can see, my problem is that the parent snaps to 100% width first and only afterwards the child slides in.

p.s. I chose a table and cells as the left width should be fixed and the right should span the remaining space to 100% width of the holding element of the table (the real setup is more complicated, but this is the gist of it).

Comment: To be honest, I can't remember, but I think I solved it using custom javascript acting on the parent and child independently (independent and simultaneous animations; or you can queue them if you wish). I can't remember finding a more elegant solution.